# How to use Epilog with Tradingchart

Tags: plotting, finance, graphics

I am making a `Tradingchart` with data returned from `Financialdata`. I find I cannot add a line to the chart by giving the option `Epilog`. (For example, to draw a line from the 1st day to the 50th day.) So which coordinate shall I tell Epilog?

```
data = FinancialData["SP500", "OHLCV", {2014, 1, 1}];
TradingChart[data,
  {Style[FinancialIndicator["SimpleMovingAverage", 5], Blue],
   Style[FinancialIndicator["SimpleMovingAverage", 20], Red],
   Style[FinancialIndicator["Volume"], Black],
   Style[FinancialIndicator["MACD"], {Green, Purple}]}, 
  Epilog -> Line[{data[[1]], data[[50]]}]]
```

When I tried this, it doesn't work. Anybody have some ideas?

Comment: That's a challenging task. The difficulty is that you have not one, but at least two plots, stacked on top of each other with each execution of `TradingChart`. So, the plot coordinates are not the same as the final coordinates which is where `Epilog` operates. I'm not sure if there is a straightforward way to accomplish this.

Comment: Trading Chart is a dynamic beast prone to change its internals in future versions. I don't think you can do it without messing with specific characteristics that will surely impair its future portability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `TradingChart` rescales the chart from 1 to 100, so in order to add `Epilog` features, you must first know the range of your dates and then rescale the values.  Here is a clunky way to do so.

```
Clear[tchartx]

tchartx[val_, limits_: data[[{1, -1}, 1]]] := 
 Rescale[AbsoluteTime[val], AbsoluteTime /@ limits, {1, 100}]

data = FinancialData["SP500", "OHLCV", {2014, 1, 1}];
TradingChart[data, {Style[
   FinancialIndicator["SimpleMovingAverage", 5], Blue], 
  Style[FinancialIndicator["SimpleMovingAverage", 20], Red], 
  Style[FinancialIndicator["Volume"], Black], 
  Style[FinancialIndicator["MACD"], {Green, Purple}]},
 Epilog -> {Thick, Red, Line[{
     {tchartx[data[[1, 1]]], data[[1, 2, 3]]},
     {tchartx[data[[250, 1]]], data[[50, 2, 3]]}
     }]}

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am not sure what line you actually wanted to draw, so I arbitrarily chose a data point for demonstration purposes only.